# OpenGL - What is the most advanced rendering method implemented in OpenGL 2.1?

Tags: java, opengl, shader

I have been using OpenGL for quite a while and I have noticed almost every single time I create some program with glsl shaders it acts different on many machines.. Now I am guessing that is because some machines don't support them partially or fully. I wanted to know what could I use to ensure there is as much compatabilty for at least OpenGL 2.1+ and still be using nice things like shaders and not using fixed pipeline like immediate mode.

Also I have noticed that on two machines that both support OpenGL 3.2 an using OpenGL 3.2 functions the outcome is different .. One has artifacts and one doesn't..

What can I do / use to ensure maximum compatabilty without having to test on one billion machine to make sure it works an that I don't have to fix things for specific machines?

EDIT: So to narrow down the question, What is the most advanced way to render in OpenGL 2.1? And can I use shaders in that version?

Comment: This question lacks any details and is quite unanswerable on such a general level. The descriptions just sound like bugs in your code.

Comment: You cannot ensure that something is going to work on a machine without testing it :P Often differences in operation are due to your code invoking undefined behavior, a driver bug or other tricky portability issues like endianness or different representations for floating-point numbers. The first two cannot be accounted for without actual run-time testing, and I am guessing from your description that most of your issues fall into undefined (or poorly defined) behavior.

Comment: Sorry about the too broad thing.. I narrowed it down..

Comment: @gopgop: "*So to narrow down the question*" That doesn't narrow anything down. What is a "rendering method"?

Comment: Mapped vbos, vertex arrays and vbos, displaylists, vbos and shaders, etc..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not easy question to answer.

I suggest staying with the lowest version of OpenGL that you accept. If your clients support OpenGL 2.1 more likely than OpenGL 4.4 then stick to 2.1.

If you have more time for development you can go higher and when particular OpenGL version is available use it. For instance when GL3.3 is supported, then use geometry shaders.

In general it depends on several factors:

- your available time for development (can you support different version, or maybe you have time only for one)
- clients (hardware of clients)
- need for advanced graphics (maybe you cannot go lower than GL3.3)

another thing are the GL drivers. Here is [a bit outdated link](http://delphigl.de/glcapsviewer/listreports.php) that can help... and [one similar stack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6422578/how-do-i-support-different-opengl-versions) question

Comment: Thanks for the answer now let's say I choose 2.1 how do I know what is compatible an what isn't?

Comment: gopgop, look at http://www.opengl.org/registry for the official specifications for each version of OpenGL. This can get very tedious very quickly, however, so a quicker way to see what version of OpenGL a function requires would be to visit http://www.opengl.org/wiki/GLAPI and pay attention to the "Core since version X.YZ" tag on the right-hand side.

Comment: @gopgop just stick with the "core" version of the OpenGL as Andon wrote. http://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man2/ and this: http://www.opengl.org/wiki/Main_Page can help. For instance: http://www.opengl.org/wiki/GlUseProgram you have info that it is core since 2.0

Comment: Can you answer my new question?